# Threaded and asyncio API library

Tags: python, asynchronous, http, meta-programming

In Python I am trying to create an API for a connected device. I want to be available for both threaded (using request) and async applications (using aiohttp).
What I've come up with is wrapping the get method of both `requests` and `aiohttp` in a decorator. This decorator is passed at init and API calls are explicitly wrapped using the passed decorator.

It works, but I'd like to know how others think of this approach ? Are there better ways or will I be running into issues later on ?

```
def threaded_gett(function):
    # The threaded decorator
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        url, params = function(*args)
        response = requests.get(url, params)
        _json = response.json()
        return function.__self__.process_response(_json)

    return wrapper

def async_gett(function):
    # The async decorator
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        url, params = function(*args)
        try:
            resp = yield from function.__self__.session.get(url, params=params)
        except Exception as ex:
            lgr.exception(ex)
        else:
            _json = yield from resp.json()
            yield from resp.release()
            return function.__self__.process_response(_json)

    # wrapping the decorator in the async coroutine decorator.
    wrapper = asyncio.coroutine(wrapper)
    return wrapper


class ThreadedApi(BaseApi):
    def __init__(self,threaded_gett):
        BaseApi.__init__(self,threaded_gett)


class AsyncApi(BaseApi):
    def __init__(self,async_gett):
        BaseApi.__init__(self,async_gett)


class BaseApi():
    def __init__(self,get_wrapper):
        self.status = get_wrapper(self.status)

    def status(self):
        return <status path>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is not complete but perhaps I've got your idea.

`self.status = get_wrapper(self.status)` looks slightly strange to me (while it works, sure).

I would prefer to use class decorators:

```
import asyncio
import functools

import aiohttp
import requests


def public(func):
    func.public = True
    return func


def sync_api(cls):
    def wrapper(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
            url, params = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            response = requests.get(url, params)
            _json = response.json()
            return self.process_response(_json)

    for name in dir(cls):
        func = getattr(cls, name)
        if getattr(func, 'public'):
            setattr(cls, name, wrapper(func))


def async_api(cls):
    def wrapper(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        @asyncio.coroutine
        def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
            url, params = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            session = self.session
            try:
                resp = yield from session.get(url, params=params)
            except Exception as ex:
                logger.exception(ex)
                raise
            try:
                _json = yield from resp.json()
                yield from resp.release()
            except Exception as ex:
                logger.exception(ex)
                resp.close()
                raise
            else:
                return self.process_response(_json)

    for name in dir(cls):
        func = getattr(cls, name)
        if getattr(func, 'public'):
            setattr(cls, name, wrapper(func))


class BaseApi:

    @public
    def status(self):
        return 'http://example.com', {}


@sync_api
class ThreadedApi(BaseApi):
    pass


@async_api
class AsyncApi(BaseApi):

    def __init__(self):
        self.session = aiohttp.Session()
```

P.S. Please keep in mind that `yield from resp.json()` may raise an exception too.

P.P.S.
If you are using Python 3.4 I strongly suggest upgrading to 3.5.

Otherwise please use famous `async def/await` syntax. 
`async with session.get()` could simplify the snippet a little.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this ! I didn't know about functools. Learned something new today ! I am bound to 3.4 as I am using this on a raspberry pi. Last time I checked it still has version 3.4...